# How to use XML - SelectNode on a .loadtest file in powershell

Tags: xpath, automation, xml-parsing, load-testing, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to read a `.loadtest` file (Visual Studio Load Test File (`.loadtest`)) from a `powershell` to try and change an attribute of a node in the `.loadtest` file.

Although the file is a `.loadtest` file, its basically an `xml` file

**the .loadtest file is like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LoadTest Name="ABC" Description="" Owner="" storage="c:\users\....\ABC.loadtest" Priority="2147483647" Enabled="true" CssProjectStructure="" CssIteration="" DeploymentItemsEditable="" WorkItemIds="" TraceLevel="None" CurrentRunConfig="Run Settings1" Id="XXXX-XXXX....XXXX" xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010">
  <Scenarios>
    <Scenario Name="ABC" DelayBetweenIterations="0" PercentNewUsers="100" IPSwitching="true" TestMixType="PercentageOfUsersRunning" ApplyDistributionToPacingDelay="true" MaxTestIterations="0" DisableDuringWarmup="false" DelayStartTime="0" AllowedAgents="">
      <ThinkProfile Value="0.2" Pattern="NormalDistribution" />
      <LoadProfile Pattern="Step" InitialUsers="10" MaxUsers="1000" StepUsers="10" StepDuration="10" StepRampTime="0" />
...
...
...
<RunConfigurations>
  <RunConfiguration Name="Run Settings1" RunDuration="43200" SampleRate="15">
  </RunConfiguration>
</RunConfigurations>
```

**Im using the code:**

```
$Content = [XML]( Get-Content -Path $Path)
$Node = $Content.SelectNodes("/LoadTest/Scenarios/Scenario/LoadProfile");
```

also tried `$Content.SelectNodes("/LoadTest/RunConfigurations/RunConfiguration");`

`SelectNodes` is working fine for app configs and `xmls` but it isn't working for this kind of file. If I check for the `$Content`, it displays

```
[DBG]: PS C:\Users\a>> $Content

 xml                                            LoadTest 
-----                                         ------------
version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"                 LoadTest
```

**So this is a valid file but it isnt letting me use SelectNode**
If I do the below, there's no output nothing:

```
[DBG]: PS C:\Users\a>> $Content.SelectNodes("/LoadTest");
```

Other details:

PS Version: 4

PS: I checked the path, the content, my commands and everything seems nice. If I just replace this with an app config file, it works absolutely fine but has an issue with this file.

Comment: Are there two or more `<Scenario>` nodes and, if yes, do you need to choose which one? Have you tried looking for other types of node in the file, just to see if it is that specific node that is a problem or whether it is all of the nodes?

Comment: @AdrianHHH theres only 1 scenario node as of now under Scenarios.. also i updated what i tried already in the question - please take a look

Comment: Also i was trying different possibilities that this isnt working and i just found out that since the node <LoadTest> has some attributes, it isnt reading!! i removed the attributes and my code worked ! even for the .loadtest file !!

Comment: BUT unfortunately I dont have a empty loadtest node and i need to work with the node with attributes in it. So how do i do that ?

Comment: Reading XML with xPath expressions can be hard. I have only done a little. I know about load tests but not so much about XML or xPath. I suggest you search on this site for xPath, maybe also adding the xPath tag to the question.

Comment: @AdrianHHH, i found a solution to this, and posted it below BUT ill just keep an eye out for any other answers for this issue. Its my first time working with xmls and xpath as well (trying to automate entire load test process)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after lot of trials, this got it working:

```
$Nodes = $Content.SelectNodes("//*") | ? {$_.LocalName -eq "LoadProfile"}
```

The reason this worked and a simple `.SelectNode("/Loadtest")` or `.SelectNode("//")` didn't work is for some reason, reading is not happening for "Loadtest" node as the **Loadtest node contains attributes**(as provided in the question above). So no matter how I tried (even tried to convert this .loadtest file to .xml and then to get node) it didn't work. I saw this select nodes get all and tried and it worked !

Comment: its weird for me to accept my own answer, but the code worked :D